# ES6 not returning result to constant variable?

Tags: es6-modules

I am trying to read a csv file and return the result to a constant variable csvFile, but then the csvFile is undefined?? when I use console.log(results.data) to print out the result, I can see all the results. But then when I try to return the results.data, the csvFile is undefined??

```
const csvFile = Papa.parse(e.target.files[0], {
            header: true,
            skipEmptyLines: true,
            complete: function (results) {
             return results.data
              //console.log(results.data)
            },
          });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`Papa.parse` uses callback (parses asynchronously), it doesn't return the result, as stated in the official documentation - https://www.papaparse.com/docs

So to use it correctly you would also need some callback to be executed inside `complete`

On the other hand if you don't want to do callbacks (to not face famous "callback hell"), you could wrap `.parse` with `Promise` and then just `await` the result

```
const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       Papa.parse(e.target.files[0], {
            header: true,
            skipEmptyLines: true,
            complete: function (results) {
             //this is where your data is and we are resolving promise with it
             resolve(results.data);
            },
            error: function(err, file, inputElem, reason) {
              reject(err);
            }
          });
});

const csvFile = await promise;
```

As also mentioned in comments, it would be good to handle errors, for that you could use `error` callback in `.parse` and reject the `Promise`.

Comment: With the first solution, csvFile is not undefined anymore, but return length of 0, no data. When I test it with if (csvFile)...the second solution is not working to many complaints to the promise

Comment: I've edited the post, first solution won't work as you think I guess, so I provided more explanation. And to the Promise what complaints exactly? You need to mark the function where you `await` as `async`?

Comment: It complains await expressions are only allowed within async function and at the top levels of modules.

Comment: const csvFile = await promise;   (await is not allowed to be here), after I took away the await, then got Promise {[[PromiseState]]: 'pending', [[PromiseResult]]: undefined}, but I can see the results

Comment: When you said I need to mark the function where await as async. So in this case I tried to put async before new Promise or async before resolve, the compiler don't allow me to do so? Am I waiting for this function Promise??

Comment: Thanks! I got it. I put the async before (resolve) and it works fine! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Always welcome @user7087799, please mark the answer as correct :)

Comment: Get rid of that first code block in your answer.  That is NEVER the right way to code this because no other code will ever know when the value in `csvFile` is valid and you should never even tempt someone to write that code. Also, this code looks like it's missing error handling of any kind.  That `.parse()` function must have a way of communicating back an error which also needs to be factored into a good solution.

Comment: @jfriend00 I’ve explained it, I wanted to show the idea, but yeah it might be confusing so I’ll remove it :)

Comment: @jfriend00 you are right about error handling as well, added that